# How to open multiple integrated terminals in vs code and run command on them?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm working on my react project so every time I want to start working I have to open 3 terminals one for `npm start` which starts the react dev server, one for `tsc -w` which watches the typescript changes, and one `sass src/sass:src/dist` for sass compiler and it takes time every time having to manually open the terminals and running the command and switch to the next one, is there a way to automate this process, like an npm script or keyboard shortcut on vs-code? and if so is there a way to split them into one page on the terminal box in vs-code so I can see all three at once just by running the script or shortcut on vs-code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK in VS Code you can't open a new integrated terminal using a shell command, but you can with Tasks. Here's an example task that runs both my frontend and backend subprojects with `npm start` in separate split integrated terminals.

You can run a task like this by hitting `F1` then typing `tasks` and hitting enter to show the list of runnable tasks. You can also run it with the hotkey `Ctrl+Shift+B` if you include `"kind": "build"` like I do below.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

[image]

`{ProjectRoot}/.vscode/tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Start Frontend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm start",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/realworld-frontend"
      },
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "new",
        "group": "groupA"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Start Backend",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "npm start",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/realworld-backend"
      },
      "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "reveal": "always",
        "focus": false,
        "panel": "new",
        "group": "groupA"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Start Both",
      "dependsOn": ["Start Frontend", "Start Backend"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```